# Interpreting a Mathematical Function in Python

Tags: python

I have a problem I'm working on where I have to produce a function which mirrors a mathematical one given: 
`Probability = e^beta / 1 + e^beta`. So far I produced code that works when I feed it an integer, but I need to use the function to calculate the probabilities of an array.

My code so far:

```py
import math
e = math.e


def likelihood(beta):
  for i in range(beta): 
    return (e**(beta)/(1+ e**(beta)))

beta_candidate = np.random.uniform(-5, 5, 50)

likelihood_candidate = likelihood(beta_candidate)
```

Whenever I run the code I'm met with an error stating: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index.

Comment: Your function takes in an integer. You are trying to feed it a list.  Consider using something like a list comprehension

Comment: The loop in your function stops after the first iteration because the function returns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
In [3]: import math

In [4]: e = math.e

In [5]: def likelihood(beta):
   ...:     return [e**i/(1+e**i) for i in beta]
   ...:

In [7]: likelihood_candidate = likelihood(beta_candidate)
```

Since you have your beta_candidate as numpy array, you can just do vectorized numpy operations:

```
l = np.exp(beta_candidate)/(1+np.exp(beta_candidate))
```